# Return an output parameter from SQL Server via a stored procedure and c#

Tags: sql-server, c#-4.0, stored-procedures, output-parameter

I am having a devil of a time getting an output value from SQL Server.

Here is my stored procedure:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[Insert_UnknownCustomer_Quote_Document]
-- Add the parameters for the stored procedure here
@NewDocumentFileName nvarchar(100),
@NewDocumentWordCount int,
@NewQuoteAmount money,
@NewQuoteNumber int OUTPUT = 0

AS

DECLARE @Today datetime
SELECT @Today = GETDATE()

BEGIN TRANSACTION
BEGIN TRY

BEGIN
-- SET NOCOUNT ON added to prevent extra result sets from interfering with SELECT statements.
SET NOCOUNT ON;


-- Insert statements for procedure here
INSERT INTO dbo.Customers(DateAdded)
VALUES (@Today)

INSERT INTO dbo.Quotes(CustomerID, QuoteAmount, QuoteDate)
VALUES (@@IDENTITY, @NewQuoteAmount, @Today)

SELECT @NewQuoteNumber = @@IDENTITY
INSERT INTO dbo.DocumentFiles(QuoteNumber, DocumentFileName, DocumentFileWordCount)
VALUES (@NewQuoteNumber, @NewDocumentFileName, @NewDocumentWordCount)

-- Return quote number
RETURN @NewQuoteNumber

END
COMMIT TRANSACTION
END TRY

BEGIN CATCH
ROLLBACK TRANSACTION
PRINT 'Transaction rolled back.'
END CATCH
```

And here is my C#:

```
SqlParameter returnQuoteNumber = new SqlParameter("@NewQuoteNumber", SqlDbType.Int);
        returnQuoteNumber.Direction = ParameterDirection.ReturnValue;
        newSQLCommand.Parameters.Add(returnQuoteNumber);
```

Here is the error I am receiving now:

```
Procedure or function 'Insert_UnknownCustomer_Quote_Document' expects parameter '@NewQuoteNumber', which was not supplied.
```

I have tried taking @NewQuoteNumber out of the beginning and placing it after the AS with a DECLARE but that produces an error, too.

Comment: FYI: `Scope_Identity()` is a much wiser choice than `@@IDENTITY`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you want  `ParameterDirection.Output`  not `ParameterDirection.ReturnValue`

Also take it out of the return part, return should be used to return a status not a value

And if you do use return, I would do it after the transaction is committed not before

Comment: Thank you very much for the help. I will mark it as answer as soon as it lets me.

Answer (score 1):

```
SqlCommand.Parameters.Add("@NewQuoteNumber", SqlDbType.Int).Direction = ParameterDirection .Output ;

<SqlCommand>.ExecuteNonQuery();

int NewQuoteNumber = int.Parse(SqlCommand.Parameters["@NewQuoteNumber"].Value .ToString ());
```

now you can use this value into your code .

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow: if you post code, XML or data samples, **please** highlight those lines in the text editor and click on the "code samples" button ( `{  }` ) on the editor toolbar to nicely format and syntax highlight it!

Answer (score 0):

this line:

```
int NewQuoteNumber = int.Parse(SqlCommand.Parameters["@NewQuoteNumber"].Value .ToString ());<br />
```

should be:

```
int NewQuoteNumber = int.Parse(SqlCommand.Parameters["NewQuoteNumber"].Value .ToString ());
```