# Count rows in a stored procedure using WebMatrix.Data in a Webmethod

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, stored-procedures, asp.net-mvc-5

I'm tying to accomplish a very basic result which is to count the number of rows in a stored procedure using WebMatrix.Data. Since I'm new to creating stored procedures and using WebMatrix.Data I would appreciate it if someone could lead me to the best practice path.

Here is what I've done so far:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[SD_photoCount]
@IDuser nvarchar (150)
AS SET NOCOUNT OFF;

SELECT Count(photos.IDphoto) AS photoCount FROM photos WHERE IDuser = @IDuser

[WebMethod]
public static string photoCount(string IDuserInput)
{   
    var photoCount_query = db.Query("Exec dbo.SD_photoCount @0", IDuserInput);
    var photoCountResult = photoCount_query.photoCount;//ERROR 
    return photoCountResult.ToString();        
}
```

The error I'm getting is the following:

Error   4   'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable' does not contain a definition for 'photoCount' and no extension method 'photoCount' accepting a first argument of type 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Comment: similar: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10645730/return-an-output-parameter-from-sql-server-via-a-stored-procedure-and-c-sharp

Comment: and this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10905782/using-stored-procedure-output-parameters-in-c-sharp